# ValueError: Shapes (32, 16) and (32,) are incompatible

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-classification

```
model.add(Conv2D(16,(3,3),1,activation='relu',input_shape=(256,256,3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),1,activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Conv2D(16,(3,3),1,activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(16,activation='softmax'))

pre=Precision()
re=Recall()
ba=BinaryAccuracy()

for batch in test.as_numpy_iterator():
    X,y=batch
    yhat=model.predict(X)
    print(X.shape,y.shape,yhat.shape)
    pre.update_state(y,yhat) -> Error Line
    re.update_state(y,yhat)
    ba.update_state(y,yhat)
```

I did write the above program. I am able to train the model, but in the above Error line I am getting an error as mentioned above. Can anyone help me with this?

I tried to classify Image into 16 different calsses. I am able to train the but getting the error in above line.

Comment: A minimum reproducible code could be helpful.

Comment: Please provide the feature and label shape of your dataset.